# how to use sequelize specific errors?

Tags: node.js, exception, sequelize.js

How do you import sequelize errors?
I want to use specific errors like `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError)` for error handling.

```js
try {
  query...
} catch(e){
  if (e instanceof SequelizeUniqueConstraintError) { 
    next(new ResourceError(e.toString(), 401))
  } else {
    next(new ResourceError(e.toString(), 500))
  }
}
```

I'm getting `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError is not defined`, but I can't seem to navigate through the sequelize instance to find any error classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the [source code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/e05351492ac535f7eff977e29041c4a2eb4ee0d6/src/errors/validation/unique-constraint-error.ts#L30) of `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError`. The class named `UniqueConstraintError`. The `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError` is the value of `name` property. It's **NOT** a JavaScript class. So you should use `UniqueConstraintError`.

E.g.

```js
import { UniqueConstraintError } from 'sequelize';

try {
  throw new UniqueConstraintError({ message: 'test unique constraint' });
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof UniqueConstraintError) {
    console.log(401);
  } else {
    console.log(500);
  }
}
```

The execution result:

```
401
```

package version: `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`